# How to draw a line between two points when holding one axis fixed (time series)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a straight line between each points of two variables, that are observed at the same time, using ggplot2. 
I looked at geom_segment but I struggle to make it work in my case.

Here is my minimum working example and a drawing of what I would like to achieve *(the part I am missing is in blue color)*.

I would appreciate any help!

```
set.seed(1234)
y <- rnorm(10,0,0.01)
Date <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 10)

example_df <- tibble(Date,y) %>% mutate(avg = mean(y))
ggplot(example_df, mapping = aes(x = Date)) + geom_point(mapping = aes(y = y)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = avg), col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: What's the logic behind these lines?

Comment: @NelsonGon they should represent the distance been the black point and the red line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`geom_segment`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html) will work:

```
ggplot(example_df, aes(x = Date)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = y)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = avg), col = "red")+
    geom_segment(aes(xend = Date, y = y, yend = avg), col = 'blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, I would have never understood how to do this by looking at the help of geom_segment. I thought I have to provide x1 (here the date), xend and y and yend always between the coordinates of 2 variables. Now I understand it better, thank you VERY much.